# Redirect from Generic View to Generic View

Tags: django, redirect, view, django-generic-views

I am building a page for user registration.
I want the customer to enter information step by step, so I want to separate the forms.
For example, entering username, password, then go to next page and enter other information.
I realize that with session.
here is the code snipet

```
class RegisterBaseView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        for name in form.register_fields:
            self.request.session.update(
                {
                    name: form.cleaned_data[name]
                 }
            )

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)



class RegisterProfileView(RegisterBaseView):
    form_class = RegisterProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('')
    template_name = 'player/register_profile.html'

class RegisterUserView(RegisterBaseView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('')
    template_name = 'player/register_user.html'
```

I want `RegisterUserView` redirect to `RegisterProfileView` directly without urls.py, because I save the object finally linking to each other.

How should I write `success_url` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't redirect to another view without the url. You are updating the `request.session` in each view. You can access the data from session using `session.get()` method. If you don't write/call a save method within the view or form, then it shouldn't save anything. In final view of the chained views, you can save the data like this:

```
class FinalView(CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
       name = self.request.session.get('name', None)
       ....
       if form.is_valid():
           data = form.cleaned_data['data']
           your_model = YourModel()
           your_model.name = name
           your_model.data = data
           your_model.save()
```

To prevent users accessing any middle view, do like this:

```
class MiddleView(SomeView):

    def form_valid(self):
        if self.request.session.get('name', None) is None:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/first_view_url')
        else:
          ....
```

Comment: Thank you, then how should I prevent from accessing the chained middle view by entering the url directly?

Comment: you can put it directly or put it by using `success_url`. Another thing, you need to put separate url associated with each view.

Comment: Is it impossible that if user directly accesses the middle view, the view blocks the user and redirects to the first chained view?

Comment: Thank you ruddra, I'll thumb up!